# Why we use mAp score for evaluate object detectors in deep learning?

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection

In this [Tensorflow detection model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) they have mentioned COCO mAp score to different detection architectures. They also has said higher the mAp score higher the accuracy . What is don't understand is **how this is calculated ? What is the maximum score it can has ? Why this mAp score is different from data set to data set ?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To understand MAP (Mean Average Precision), I would start with AP (Average Precision) first.

> Suppose we are searching for images of a flower and we provide our
>   image retrieval system a sample picture of a rose (query), we do get
>   back a bunch of ranked images (from most likely to least likely).
>   Usually not all of them are correct. So we compute the precision at
>   every correctly returned image, and then take an average.

---

**Example:**

> If our returned result is `1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1` where `1` is an image of a flower,
>   while `0` not, then the precision at every correct point is:

```
Precision at each correct image = 1/1, 0, 0, 2/4, 3/5, 4/6
Summation of these precisions = 83/30
Average Precision = (Precision summation)/(total correct images) = 83/120
```

---

**Side note:**

*This section provides a detailed explanation behind the calculation of precision at each correct image in case you're still confused by the above fractions.*

For illustration purposes, let `1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1` be stored in an array so `results[0] = 1`, `results[1] = 0` etc.

Let `totalCorrectImages = 0, totalImagesSeen = 0, pointPrecision = 0`

The formula for `pointPrecision` is `totalCorrectImages / totalImagesSeen`

At `results[0], totalCorrectImages = 1, totalImagesSeen = 1` hence `pointPrecision = 1`

Since `results[1] != 1`, we ignore it but `totalImagesSeen = 2 && totalCorrectImages = 1`

Since `results[2] != 1`, `totalImagesSeen = 3 && totalCorrectImages = 1`

At `results[3], totalCorrectImages = 2, totalImagesSeen = 4` hence `pointPrecision = 2/4`

At `results[4], totalCorrectImages = 3, totalImagesSeen = 5` hence `pointPrecision = 3/5`

At `results[5], totalCorrectImages = 4, totalImagesSeen = 6` hence `pointPrecision = 4/6`

---

> A simple way to interpret is to produce a combination of zeros and
>   ones which will give the required AP. For example, an AP of 0.5 could
>   have results like `0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, ...` where every second image is
>   correct, while an AP of `0.333` has `0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, ...` where
>   every third image is correct.
>
> For an AP of `0.1`, every 10th image will be correct, and that is
>   definitely a bad retrieval system. On the other hand, for an AP above
>   `0.5`, we will encounter more correct images than wrong in the top results which is definitely a good sign.

MAP is just an extension of AP. You simply take the averages of all the AP scores for a certain number of queries. The above interpretation of AP scores also holds true for MAP. MAP ranges from 0 to 100, higher is better.

AP formula on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_measures_(information_retrieval)#Average_precision)

MAP formula on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_measures_(information_retrieval)#Mean_average_precision)

Credits to this [blog](https://makarandtapaswi.wordpress.com/2012/07/02/intuition-behind-average-precision-and-map/)

**EDIT I:**

The same concept is applied when it comes to object detection. In this scenario you would calculate the AP for each class. This is given by the area under the precision-recall curve for a given class. From this point, you find their averages to attain the mAP.

For more details, refer to section 3.4.1 and 4.4 of the [2012 Pascal VOC Dev Kit](http://host.robots.ox.ac.uk/pascal/VOC/voc2012/devkit_doc.pdf). The related paper can be found [here](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/ckiw/postscript/ijcv_voc09.pdf).

Comment: Hi can you explain this what is mean by "So we compute the precision at every correctly returned image" ?

Comment: I believe the example provided right after that sentence answers your question. You compute the precision only on the correct predictions ignoring the false ones.

Comment: so what is the AP at last . The last thing ?

Comment: Well it's different when calculating this for image detection . I am asking what the effect of mAp in detection such as SSD.

Comment: @ShamaneSiriwardhana Dude, its the same concept. I used the `0` and `1` as an example to help you understand the concept behind it. For object detection, you'd calculate the average precision for each class. This is given by the area under the precision-recall curve for a given class. From this point you find the averages which in turn give you mAP. Read section 3.4.1 and 4.4 of [Pascal VOC doc](http://host.robots.ox.ac.uk/pascal/VOC/voc2012/devkit_doc.pdf) The official paper can be found [here](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/ckiw/postscript/ijcv_voc09.pdf)

Comment: yeah. So for each image there can be some number of detection . Then we do the calculation right ?